# JavaScript not functioning in .fcc file

Tags: javascript

I have a HTML log-in page that has to be converted to .fcc for our SAML.

In the .fcc page I have a simple inline JavaScript that validates the entries.

This JavaScript runs perfectly in the HTML file but once it gets converted to .fcc it just fails to fire.

The script is called on the form onsubmit.

Has anyone seen this behavior before with JavaScript and .fcc and know a workaround? Google draws a blank.

Comment: What's an `.fcc` file? And how do you "convert" to it?

Comment: Contains authentication settings for logging in a user; written in a simple markup language that includes HTML and some custom notation.

The FCC authentication file is typically named "login.fcc".